# Enable a TButton of an MDI ChildForm upon closing of another MDI ChildForm

Tags: delphi, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

I have 2 MDI ChildForms and the Child1 has a TButton to open the Child2. I do not have any issue opening it at the same time disable the TButton to prevent Child2 from recreating again using TButton.

Now, the challenge comes when I want the TButton of Child1 back to "enabled" when I closed the Child2.

I am getting access error when doing these code:

```
procedure TfrmChild2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  child1_u.frmChild1.btnOpenChild2Form.Enabled := True;
  Action := caFree;
end;
```

I understand there is somehow a different approach when dealing with MDI. I figured it out when I did the code for disabling the TButton during opening at runtime below:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnOpenChild2(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TfrmChild2.Create(frmMain);
  btnOpenChild2.Enabled := False;
end;
```

But to enable it back when the Child2 form is closed is a challenge.

I tried to create a procedure in the MainForm (Owner) to trigger the enable of TButton in the Child1:

```
procedure TfrmMain.EnableButtonAtChild1();
begin
  child1_u.frmChild1.btnOpenChild1Form.Enabled := True;  
end;
```

and called at runtime during OnClose of Child2:

```
procedure TfrmChild2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  EnableButtonAtChild1();
end;
```

I am new to MDI and I need to understand how accessing components works particular this simple case. I will appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a different approach - assign the 2nd child's `OnClose` event dynamically when the 1st child creates the 2nd child.  Don't have the 2nd child try to find and access the 1st child directly:

```pascal
procedure TfrmChild1.btnOpenChild2FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  child: TfrmChild2;
begin
  child := TfrmChild2.Create(Application.MainForm);
  child.OnClose := Child2Closed;
  btnOpenChild2Form.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TfrmChild1.Child2Closed(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  btnOpenChild2.Enabled := True;
  Action := caFree;
end;
```

Just make sure the 2nd child is always closed before the 1st child is freed, otherwise you will have trouble.  If you need to, you can solve that like this:

```pascal
procedure TfrmChild1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  child: TForm;
  event: TCloseEvent;
begin
  for I := 0 to Application.MainForm.MDIChildCount-1 do
  begin
    child := Application.MainForm.MDIChildren[I];
    event := child.OnClose;
    if Assigned(event) and (TMethod(event).Data = Self) then
      child.OnClose := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Works! like charm! Thank you so much @Remy Lebeau!

Comment: Hi @Remy Lebeau. Sorry to bother you with this minor error. I am getting an error on the TMethod and .Data as Undeclared Identifier. I thought there should be component I missed in the uses but no idea after searching some help in the internet. Any idea with this error?

Comment: `TMethod` is in the `System` unit, you should not be getting any "undeclared identifier" errors on it.

Comment: I tried the second procedure 'FormDestroy' above in my new case and it works but there is another issue that floats — the 'Action := caFree;' did not fires. Instead, it just simply goes back to minimize window. I did not notice this previously.